# Find and replace multiple pairs of chars

Tags: regex, text, sed

I have a text file and use `sed` editor with regex to find and replace characters in it. Say, a->b, g->h, r->d and e->q.

Like this:

```
sed -i "s/a/b/g" file.html >NUL
sed -i "s/g/h/g" file.html >NUL
sed -i "s/r/d/g" file.html >NUL
sed -i "s/e/q/g" file.html >NUL
```

All works fine. But I want to combine this into a single regex line. Can I? After googling and reading a lot about refex, I see no way right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tr is the command to do this: `tr < file.html 'agre' 'bhdq'`

But if you're asking how to make commands run together go:

```
sed -e "s/a/b/g" -e "s/g/h/g" -e "s/r/d/g" -e "s/e/q/g" file.html
```

Or more generally if the commands are different:

```
sed -e "s/a/b/g" file.html | sed -e "s/g/h/g" |
    sed -e "s/r/d/g" | sed -e "s/e/q/g"
```

Comment: +1 for the tr answer, hopefully the OP understands that is THE correct way to do this..

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 'y/agre/bhdq' file
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` commands can also be read from a file: `sed -f commands.sed file.html`

```
commands.sed
---- 
s/a/b/g
s/g/h/g
s/r/d/g
s/e/q/g
```